# Stop uploading file if encountered an error on a block of if else statements

Tags: php

Is there any way to check if there will be an error on file uploading? Like putting a variable to know if there's an error on every else statement so that before it will prevent running the query. Because what's happening is even there's an error on moving/copying/deleting a file, it still runs the query.

```
$dir = './uploads/images/';

if ($_FILES['thumbnail']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['thumbnail']['error'] > 0){
        $new_path = $dir;
        $new_file = $new_path . $exist_tn;

        $move = rename($cur_file,$new_file);
        if ($move) {
            $thumbnail = $exist_tn;
        } else {
            echo "Error Moving File.";
        }
        
    }else{      
        $thumbnail = $thumb;
        $deletefile = unlink($cur_file);
        if($deletefile){
            $targetPath = $dir.$thumbnail;
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
            $movefile = move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath);
            if ($movefile) {
                echo "File upload successfully.";
            }else{
                echo "Upload File Failed.";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Delete File failed.";
        }
    }

        $query = '
            UPDATE
                `mytbl` 
            SET 
                `title` = "'.$title.'",
                `thumbnail` ="'.$thumbnail.'",
                `date` = "'.$date.'",
                `part` = "'.$part.'",
                `tags`= "'.$tags.'" 
            WHERE
                `id` = "'.$id.'"
            ';

            $update = mysqli_query(db(),$query);
            //Check if there's an error first then run query
            if (checkCondition) {
                if($update === TRUE){
                    echo "sql_update";
                }else{
                    echo "sql_error";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error Found";
            }
```

Comment: You should not be using `rename` here, but the dedicated function that exists specifically for this purpose in the context of file uploads – https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php And the return value of that will tell you, whether moving of the file succeeded, or not.

Comment: oh no.. the variables consists of mysqli_real_escape_string. I just didn't include it in this post because my main purpose is to collect first the error

Comment: And to not execute the query at the end, you can use a simple _flag_ to keep track of your error status. `$didErrorsOccur = false;` at the beginning of the whole process, and then you simple set that to `true`, when an error occurs somewhere. And before you make your query, you check what that flag contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exit after echo if you don't want the query to run
e.g
$dir = './uploads/images/';

```
if ($_FILES['thumbnail']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['thumbnail']['error'] > 0){
        $new_path = $dir;
        $new_file = $new_path . $exist_tn;

        $move = rename($cur_file,$new_file);
        if ($move) {
            $thumbnail = $exist_tn;
        } else {
            echo "Error Moving File.";
        exit();
        }
        
    }else{      
        $thumbnail = $thumb;
        $deletefile = unlink($cur_file);
        if($deletefile){
            $targetPath = $dir.$thumbnail;
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
            $movefile = move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath);
            if ($movefile) {
                echo "File upload successfully.";
            }else{
                echo "Upload File Failed.";
                exit();
            }

        }else{
            echo "Delete File failed.";
      exit();
        }
    }

        $query = '
            UPDATE
                `mytbl` 
            SET 
                `title` = "'.$title.'",
                `thumbnail` ="'.$thumbnail.'",
                `date` = "'.$date.'",
                `part` = "'.$part.'",
                `tags`= "'.$tags.'" 
            WHERE
                `id` = "'.$id.'"
            ';

            $update = mysqli_query(db(),$query);
            //Check if there's an error first then run query
            if (checkCondition) {
                if($update === TRUE){
                    echo "sql_update";
                }else{
                    echo "sql_error";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error Found";
            }
```

Comment: oh right! yeah, I forgot that exit() thank you so much!